# Including a JAR library to android project and starting an activity from it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

I'm trying to create a Library project in Android and use that library in other projects.

I've created a simple Library project, with one layout that shows some text. Checked it's set to 'is Library' and on went.

I took the Jar file that was created in the 'bin' directory, copied to a new project to the 'assets' folder (tried the 'libs' approach as well, same results).

I've checked in 'properties -> java build path -> order and export' and it's there and is selected.

In the application I'm trying to launch an Activity from the library, using:

```
    Button btnLoad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLoadLibrary);
    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LibraryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

Having imported the library:

```
import com.example.superlibrary.LibraryActivity;
```

No errors here.

Then, when I launch the application and push the button, I get:

```
05-01 20:24:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(19011): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 20:24:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(19011): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.superlibrary.R$layout
05-01 20:24:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(19011):    at com.example.superlibrary.LibraryActivity.onCreate(LibraryActivity.java:12)
05-01 20:24:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(19011):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-01 20:24:07.030: E/AndroidRuntime(19011):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
```

To make sure, I've checked the manifest file of the application and I have there:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.superlibrary.LibraryActivity"
        android:label="LibraryActivity" >
    </activity>
```

So it's being recognized and included...

Any ideas why this error would happen? (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

According to the docs

However, a library project differs from a standard Android application project in that you cannot compile it directly to its own .apk and run it on an Android device. Similarly, you cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application and building that application.

When you build an application that depends on a library project, the SDK tools compile the library into a temporary JAR file and uses it in the main project, then uses the result to generate the .apk.

**You cannot export a library project to a JAR file**.

A library cannot be distributed as a binary file (such as a JAR file). This will be added in a future version of the SDK Tools.

You need to refer a library project in your android project.

Check the below link.

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Comment: I think that in SDK-17 you CAN do that - at least that's what written in some places.

Comment: @roman i just quoted the above from the docs. I do not see like what you said in your first comment

Comment: i am not sure but i think you can enable proguard for library code as well. I have not able to get the link. I guess i saw it somewhere on SO.

Comment: Thanks - When I use the suggested way in the documentation - it does work. I guess after all you can't compile a library to a JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is very finicky with adding External Libs, the only approach I have ever had work was copying and pasting the lib to the lib folder of the project then opening Eclipse and in the new project right click on the project in the Project Explorer and left clicking on Refresh.  With that being said make sure the library appears in both the libs folder and the Android Dependencies folder
As shown in the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Then you need to check your Java build path, this error is telling you you incorrectly added a library.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to include a jar to android project and start an activity from it.
The following link discusses in depth on how to create a library project and how to reference the library project in detail

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

The following code lets you start an activity from the jar

```
final Intent it = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
it.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), "<complete path of the Activity class>");
startActivity(it);
```